# BAsic jquery slider not working

Tags: jquery, slider

Can anyone tell me why this slider is not showing?

http://jsfiddle.net/sTJCh/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have not provided any styles or inlcuded the default styles provided by jQuery UI you are not seeing anything on the UI. In the resource section you can provide the css file.

Css
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/sTJCh/6/

Comment: you have to wait for 8 mins before you can mark it as an answer for some reason.... done now

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the css file for jQuery.
You can do that in jsFiddle using the button on the left called Add Resources and adding this one: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/c5MC3/1/